# Socket programming client side

Tags: c, sockets, client, tcpclient

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>

struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
char serv_ip[]="respective ip address";
unsigned short serv_port=9001;
char rbuff[128],w1buff[128],w2buff[128],w3buff[128];
int r, w1,w2,w3;

int main() {
    int skfd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if(skfd < 0) {
        printf("\nCLIENT ERROR: Cannot create socket\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(serv_port);  
    inet_aton(serv_ip, (&serv_addr.sin_addr));  
    
    /**/int connect1 = connect(skfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    
    if(connect1 < 0) {
        printf("\nCLIENT ERROR: Cannot connect\n");
        close(skfd);
        exit(1);
    }/**/
    printf("\nCLIENT: Connected to the server\n");
    for(;;) {
        gets(w1buff);
        gets(w2buff);
        gets(w3buff);
        w1=write(skfd,w1buff,128);
        w2=write(skfd,w2buff,128);
        w3=write(skfd,w3buff,128);
        if (w1<0 || w2<0 || w3<0) {
            printf("\nCLIENT ERROR: Cannot send message to the echo server\n");
            close(skfd);
            exit(1);
        }   
        r = read(skfd, rbuff, 128);
        if (r<0) 
            printf("\nCLIENT ERROR: Cannot receive message from client.\n");
        else {
            if(r<0)
                printf("\nCLIENT ERROR: Cannot receive message from the server.\n");
            else {
                rbuff[r]='\0';
                printf("\nCLIENT: Res: %s \n",rbuff);
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The server side is running alright. But while running the client side I'm getting "cannot connect". Yes, the port number and the IP address is the same for both.
I'm using IPv4.
I am running this in a VM.

Comment: Use `perror` instead of `printf` when checking error conditions.  That will tell you *why* a library call failed.

Comment: @dbush changed it, it is saying connection refused

Comment: [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used) Probably doesn't have anything to do with your issue but worth knowing since many compilers will refuse to compile code that uses it.

Comment: How do you know the server side is working?

Comment: @RC5413 Then either you have the wrong IP/port for the server or the server process isn't running.

Comment: @IanAbbott It is printing the desired line I want it to. Thats why i assumed, it is running fine

Comment: @dbush I swear both are same. I am running this in VM. Is the problem related to that?

Comment: @RC5413 If the IP/port is correct then the server process that you're attempting to connect to isn't running.  If the server is your own code you should post that as well.

Comment: "It is printing the desired line" Since we can't see that code I have to assume the desired line has nothing to do with actually accepting a connection so it is questionable if the server is actually working fine.

Comment: @RetiredNinja The server code has been run before and it worked perfectly.  And there has been no changes made to it since.

Comment: @dbush I am not allowed to post questions before two days

Comment: @RC5413 I mean include the server code in this post, as it's relevant to the question.

Comment: If the server works it must have worked with a client. What is different between that client and this new one? Does the old client still work in the configuration you're now running? Based on experience it can be pretty easy to mess up networking in a VM. Have you tried something simple like connecting to the server with telnet?

Comment: @RetiredNinja nothing new. I ran this code in the college machine. I am thinking about running it on host OS using WSL and see if it works. Thank you though

Comment: Could the connection be being refused by a firewall between the client and the server?

Comment: @IanAbbott This I dont know, so can be a possibility

Comment: @IanAbbott It was a very stupid error and it finally worked. thank you for your patience

Comment: @RC5413 Care to share what it was? 3 common reasons for a "connection refused" error: 1) the requested IP/Port is not reachable or listening. 2) the requested IP/Port is reachable and listening, but its backlog of pending connections is full. 3) a firewall or antimalware is blocking the connection. There is actually a 4th possible reason, but I can't remember what it is right now.

Comment: @RemyLebeau It was an error in the server code. I dont how it changed. I just did copy paste. while assigning the port number instead of serv_addr.sin_port, I wrote cli_addr.sin_port lol. Guess, the server was not running alright. so basically mistyped the variable name

Comment: @RC5413 it was running, just not on the port you were expecting. So that error falls into #1 that I mentioned. The client was trying to connect to a port that wasn't listening.